# PHP Post JSON With CURL

Tags: php, json, api, curl, post

I'm trying to post JSON by using CURL, and I created a table to store the data and the response I get from the url that Im sending the data to.

However, the response keeps saying that my "Post data is empty", and I can't figure out why.

I tested it with websites like https://reqbin.com/ with the data that is stored in my table and it works fine, since I get a "successful" response.

Can someone help me figure out why my data keeps being emptied?

Below is my code

```
$url = "url that im trying to post Json to.";
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($json_object));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I've also tried using the http_build_query but it does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

PHP recognizes `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` standard data type by default

// one

```
$post = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
```

// two

```
$post = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: can you be more specific? the url is receiving the data with file_get_content("php:/;input")

Comment: your CURL request header contain Content-Type: application/json , So you need to use file_get_contents("php://input") to get the request data 

`
$post = file_get_contents("php://input"); $post = json_decode($post);
`